# ¿Cómo añado la clase cada vez que hago click?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Para que se entienda, lo que es la clase es una animación y quiero que se repita cada vez que se le hace click al botón. Imagino que tengo que agregar la clase y luego quitarla y así sucesivamente pero no logro hacerlo con código...

```
let bloqueCambiar = document.getElementById("bloque");
let contador = 0;
function funcionClick (){ // funcionClick sale de la funcion agregada al botón en html.
    contador++;
    bloqueCambiar.classList.add("tamaño");
    console.log(contador);
}
```

Acá me quedo, ya probé con bucles, condicionales, pero no logro encontrar la lógica para que me salga. Ayuda porfa soy muy nuevo en javascript

Answer (score 3):

Cambia esto

```
bloqueCambiar.classList.add("tamaño");
```

Por esto

```
bloqueCambiar.classList.toggle("tamaño");
```

Lo que hace toggle es remover si ya fue agregada la clase anteriormente, o bien agregar la clase si el elemento no la tiene, asi puedes intercalar la apariencia de tu elemento.

Según [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

> `toggle( String [, force] )`
> Cuando sólo hay un argumento presente: Alterna el valor de la clase; ej., si la clase existe la elimina y devuelve false, si no, la
> añade y devuelve true.
> Cuando el segundo argumento está presente: Si el segundo argumento se evalúa como true, se añade la clase indicada, y si se evalúa como
> false, la elimina.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Aprendí un metodo nuevo que está muy bueno, sin embargo me gustaria que cada click repita la animacion y no tenga que andar haciendo un click para eliminar la clase y otro para agregarla, digamos que el click solo la agregue y que la clase se elimine sola. Asi siempre que haga click figura la animación